Programatically find out generic constraints of a function type
Let's assume I have some simple functions like this, with a derived type:
type SomeFunction = <T extends string>(a:number, b:T) => {number:T}

I want to infer the output type of a list of similar functions depending on the passed props, but I don't know the list of functions in advance. For that, I reason, I need to know what is the argument that defines the generic part and what are its constraints.
My naive impulse is to define a generic function that they all extend and try to infer what their constraints are (here I'm ignoring the step of not knowing which argument to test for):
type GenericFunction<T> = <G extends T>(...arg:[any, G]) => any
type Test = SomeFunction extends GenericFunction<string> ? true : false // true

So far so good. But trying to use something like this:
type GenericFunction<T> = <G extends T>(...arg:[any, G]) => any
type Test = SomeFunction extends GenericFunction<infer U> ? U : false // false

From what I understand, <G extends T> works the opposite way from how we can usually infer things. As in, GenericFunction<never> extends SomeFunction, but GenericFunction<any> does not, it can be an extension of only something like type SomeOtherFunction = <T extends any>(a:number, b:T) => {number:T}. Is there any possibility to pass this hurdle?
Playground

You can't do it that way, and you can't use infer in the constraint clause in a helpful way due to ms/TS#41040. You can rely on generic erasure like this playground link shows, which gives you string. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz alas, it was only the first step building up for a case where I don't know which argument is the generic one. But I guess this answers the question - that it's simply impossible.

I'm a little confused because your question is about passing a particular hurdle, which the approach I've shown does. The fact that you cannot then go on to abstract over which parameter, if any, is the generic one, isn't affected by that. Yes, I do believe it's currently impossible, because of TS#41040. The workaround mentioned there is the same one I've shown. Shall I write an answer that shows the workaround and also that the underlying use case is probably unsatisfiable in TS at present?
